# Difference between NTILE in SQL and spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, window-functions

I have the following dataframe/dataset:

```
+--+-----------+-----+
|Id|Date       |Value|
+---------------------
|1| 2021-08-11|  4.0 |
|1| 2021-08-12|  1.0 |
|1| 2021-08-13|  4.0 |
|1| 2021-08-14|  2.0 |
|1| 2021-08-15|  4.0 |
|1| 2021-08-16|  1.0 |
|1| 2021-08-17|  2.0 |
|1| 2021-08-18|  0.0 |
|1| 2021-08-19|  0.0 |
|1| 2021-08-20|  2.0 |
|1| 2021-08-21|  2.0 |
|1| 2021-08-22|  4   |
|1| 2021-08-23|  1.0 |
|1| 2021-08-24|  3.0 |
+-+-----------+------+

(In SQL Table the column `Value` is integer)
```

I'm using the following query in MSSQL Server to get the NTILEs

```sql
SELECET ntile(4) over (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Value)
```

In pyspark, I'm using:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("Id").orderBy("Value")

df = df.withColumn(
   "ntile",
   f.ntile(4).over(w)
)
```

Although, I got different outputs for each query:

My SQL output:

```
+--------------+
|NTILE(SQL)    |
---------------+
|             4|
|             2|
|             4|
|             2|
|             4|
|             1|
|             2|
|             1|
|             1|
|             2|
|             3|
|             3|
|             1|
|             3|
+--------------+
```

My PySpark output:

```
+--------------+
|NTILE(Spark)  |
---------------+
|             4|
|             1|
|             4|
|             2|
|             4|
|             1|
|             2|
|             1|
|             1|
|             2|
|             3|
|             3|
|             2|
|             3|
+--------------+
```

**Why I am getting different outputs since the querys/logic are the same? Is NTILE in PySpark different from SQL Server? I'm using spark 3.2.1...**

*NOTE: I've noticed that changing `Value` column type (i.e., integer to double), my ntile changes the output*

Comment: Can you show the output including the Date column? There is the same number of each NTILE value (1-4) in both outputs, so it could be the same output just unsorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is no difference in value results, just output order.

Add an additional column, something that will identify the record and run it again.

Comment: Yes, I ordered by `date` column too. Since values were  repeating in `Value` column, the `ntile` function sets the ntile in a randomic way. Using `date` column` I have a unique `date` for each `Value`. This solved my problem, thanks!